# gdb not loading symbols after attaching to process (MySQL debug binary)

Tags: mysql, linux, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to use `gdb` to step-debug `mysql` internals.

I compiled the debug binary (`Server version: 8.0.28-debug Source distribution` ), but it doesn't seem like `gdb` can access most of the symbols.

When I attach `gdb` to a running server process, then send a MySQL query in another terminal, `gdb` breaks at some OS level function, and the query terminal does get paused. But when I try to "step into," the query result is returned without me getting to peek into any code.

When I run `info sources` or `info functions` in `gdb`, almost nothing seems to be from `mysql`, except a few under MySQL's `extras` directory. Scrolling way down the `info functions` output, below `Non-debugging symbols` I finally see a bunch of `mysql` functions. So, they don't appear to be loaded.

I started `mysqld` with the `--gdb=ON --debug=ON` flags, and also tried setting the SESSION variable for debugging in the `MySQL` terminal:

```
mysql> SET SESSION debug = 'd:t:i:o,/tmp/mysqld.trace:F:L:N:P';
```

Nothing I've tried has worked yet.

Here's my whole setup, from the point of launching a `vagrant` VM with `Ubuntu` 20.04. I basically followed the steps [here](http://zhangyushao.site/notes/mysql/software/2020/09/19/install-mysql-from-source.html), modified for a `debug` install.

```
$ apt update
$ apt upgrade -y
$ apt install libssl-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config bison build-essential –y
$ cd ~
$ mkdir bld
$ cd bld
$ ################
$ ## BUILD STEP ##
$ ################
$ cmake /vagrant/mysql-server/ -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=$HOME/my_boost \
    -DWITH_DEBUG=true -DWITH_INNODB_EXTRA_DEBUG=true
$ # /vagrant folder is mounted from the Windows 10 host OS, contains the mysql git repo
$ make -j8
$ make install
$ ###
$ groupadd mysql
$ useradd -r -g mysql -s /bin/false mysql
$ cd /usr/local/mysql-test
$ mkdir mysql-files
$ chown mysql:mysql mysql-files
$ chmod 750 mysql-files
$ ###
$ /usr/local/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql
$ # I dont need "secure" on local VM
$ 
$ ##################################
$ # START THE SERVER FOR DEBUGGING #
$ ##################################
$ /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --gdb=ON --debug=ON --thread_cache_size=5
$ # get mysqld PID
$ ps aux | grep mysql
root        2565  0.0  0.0  11856  4492 pts/0    S    07:12   0:00 sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql --debug=ON --gdb=ON
root        2566  0.0  0.0   2608  1808 pts/0    S    07:12   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --debug=ON --gdb=ON
mysql       2667  1.1  4.0 1818376 415952 pts/0  Sl   07:12   0:11 /usr/local/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local --datadir=/usr/local/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/lib/plugin --user=mysql --debug=ON --gdb=ON --log-error=vagrant.err --pid-file=vagrant.pid
vagrant     2745  0.0  0.0   8900   736 pts/1    S+   07:29   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
$ # START GDB
$ gdb
(gdb) attach 2667
Attaching to process 2667
[New LWP 2670]
[New LWP 2671]
[New LWP 2672]
[New LWP 2673]
[New LWP 2674]
[New LWP 2675]
[New LWP 2676]
[New LWP 2677]
[New LWP 2678]
[New LWP 2679]
[New LWP 2680]
[New LWP 2681]
[New LWP 2682]
[New LWP 2683]
[New LWP 2684]
[New LWP 2685]
[New LWP 2688]
[New LWP 2689]
[New LWP 2690]
[New LWP 2691]
[New LWP 2692]
[New LWP 2693]
[New LWP 2694]
[New LWP 2695]
[New LWP 2696]
[New LWP 2697]
[New LWP 2701]
[New LWP 2702]
[New LWP 2703]
[New LWP 2704]
[New LWP 2705]
[New LWP 2706]
[New LWP 2707]
[New LWP 2708]
[New LWP 2709]
[New LWP 2711]
[New LWP 2713]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f200fe2faff in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f1ffecb87d0, nfds=2, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
29      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

None of the post-attach output mentions `mysql`. `gdb` does not seem to be importing the symbols.

[This tutorial](https://apprize.best/data/mysql/6.html) suggests that the `gdb` output after `attach [PID]` should look more like the following, with a line ike `Reading symbols from ... mysqld...done.`:

```
(gdb) attach 7506
Attaching to process 7506
Reading symbols from /home/cbell/source/bzr/mysql-5.6/sql/mysqld...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba8e57700 (LWP 7524)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba4a26700 (LWP 7523)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba5227700 (LWP 7522)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba5a28700 (LWP 7521)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba6229700 (LWP 7520)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba6a2a700 (LWP 7519)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba722b700 (LWP 7518)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba7a2c700 (LWP 7517)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba822d700 (LWP 7516)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba8a2e700 (LWP 7515)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba9658700 (LWP 7513)]
[New Thread 0x7f7ba9e59700 (LWP 7512)]
[New Thread 0x7f7baa65a700 (LWP 7511)]
[New Thread 0x7f7baae5b700 (LWP 7510)]
[New Thread 0x7f7bab65c700 (LWP 7509)]
[New Thread 0x7f7bb085f700 (LWP 7508)]
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007f7bb0939ae3 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: "For boolean options, the value may be specified as 1 or ON to enable the option, or as 0 or OFF to disable the option."  (from: [MySQL Source-Configuration Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/source-configuration-options.html))  and you seem to be using `true`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, those are the exact commands I ar issued. I’m not sure where I got ‘true’ from. I didn’t see any error messages due to that. And I confirmed that the MySQL binary was the debug version. So I don’t think that was the issue. But I did recompile using ‘1’ and **also added** the ‘-DWITH_VALGRIND’, and now I’m able to step through the code. I need to do a few more tests before I can be sure what did it, though. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the short answer. You need both `-DWITH_DEBUG` and `-DWITH_VALGRIND`.

```
cmake /vagrant/mysql-server/ -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=$HOME/my_boost \
    -DWITH_DEBUG=1 -DWITH_INNODB_EXTRA_DEBUG=1 -DWITH_VALGRIND=1
```

(Note: The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/compiling-for-debugging.html) makes no mention of requiring VALGRIND for step debugging, as far as I can see)

It appears that `-DWITH_DEBUG` alone is more for debugging crashes, and it seems to provide symbols for system calls. Compiling with the `-DWITH_VALGRIND` flag appears to be what gets the vast quantity of internals' symbols loaded.

Running pretty much all these commands with `sudo`.

```
apt update
apt upgrade -y
apt install libssl-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config bison build-essential –y
cd ~
mkdir bld
cd bld
################
## BUILD STEP ##
################
cmake /vagrant/mysql-server/ -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=$HOME/my_boost \
    -DWITH_DEBUG=true -DWITH_INNODB_EXTRA_DEBUG=true -DWITH_VALGRIND
# /vagrant is mounted from Windows host OS, contains the mysql git repo
make -j8
# make install # NOT NEEDED FOR DEBUGGING
###
groupadd mysql
useradd -r -g mysql -s /bin/false mysql
# cd /usr/local/mysql-test # instead, just go to build/mysql-test/
# or find . -name 'mysql-test'
cd ~/bld/mysql-test/
mkdir mysql-files
chown mysql:mysql mysql-files
chmod 750 mysql-files
###
~/bld/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mysql
# I dont need "secure" on local VM    
##################################
# START THE SERVER FOR DEBUGGING #
##################################
# running mysqld directly - no mysqld_safe in bld
~/bld/bin/mysqld --user=mysql --gdb=1 --debug=1 --thread_cache_size=5
# get mysqld PID
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/mysql-server/sql$ ps aux | grep mysql
root       41292  0.0  0.0  11860  2112 pts/1    S    Feb12   0:00 sudo ./mysqld --user=mysql --gdb=1
mysql      41293  0.0  0.2 1819176 27684 pts/1   tl   Feb12   0:27 ./mysqld --user=mysql --gdb=1   
vagrant    44081  0.0  0.0   9032   736 pts/1    S+   02:11   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

# START GDB and attach to process owned by user mysql
gdb
(gdb) attach  41293
```

Notes:
Although I've had issues with folders mounted from windows in vagrant in the past, that ended up being a non-issue here. It seems that VALGRIND was all I was really missing.

I'd also note that the build time on my vagrant machine took a long time with VALGRIND, and results in 16G size. With just VALGRIND (just DEBUG), the size was only 4.5G. Using a `c5.2xlarge` instance on AWS EC2, I was able to build much faster (down to 20-30 minutes vs over 1 hour).

Answer (score 1):

> `$ make -j8`
> `$ make install`

It is *exceedingly likely* that `make install` runs `strip` on the binary before installing it into `/usr/loca/bin` (that's the standard procedure).

What you want to do is use the "as built" binary (which presumably still has debug info) to debug the process. Something like:

```
gdb ~/bld/.../mysqld -p 2667
```

> This tutorial suggests that the gdb output after ...
> `Reading symbols from /home/cbell/source/bzr/mysql-5.6/sql/mysqld...done.`

Note that they are *not* running *installed* binary, but the binary from their build tree.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions. I found the "as built" binary and ran it `~/bld/runtime_output_directory/mysqld --user=mysql --gdb=ON --debug=ON` but the result is the same. Do I need to tell `gdb` where to find source files or symbols? Does it matter what location I'm in when I run `gdb`? Currently running from `~/bld` and assuming `gdb` can get the source files from the executable since I didn't move them anywhere.